# Get results with various WHERE combinations within the same JOIN

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm trying to work out the best way to get all "searchproducts" which have parts with specified attributes. This is what I have at the moment, but this won't return anything despite their being a part that has both attributes/attribute headers.

```
SELECT DISTINCT * FROM searchproduct
JOIN part ON searchproduct.id = part.searchproduct_id
LEFT JOIN part_attribute ON part.id = part_attribute.part_id
JOIN part_attribute ON part_attribute.id = part_attribute.part_attributeheader_id
WHERE (part_attribute.name = 'Colour' AND part_attribute.value IN ('Black')) AND (part_attribute.name = 'Size' AND part_attribute.value IN ('11'));
```

Each `searchproduct` has multiple `part`, each `part` has multiple `part_attribute`, each `part_attribute` has one `part_attributeheader`, each `part_attributeheader` has one `name`.

I am thinking I possibly need to add some sort of grouping? Everything I have tried returns no results.

Here's an example of the data (is there a better way to show it?)

```
samplesearchproduct     (searchproduct)
        |
        v
     part B             (part)
     |     |
     v     v
   "11"  "Black"        (part_attribute.value)
     |     |
     v     v
  "Size"  "Colour"      (part_attributeheader.name)
```

Comment: You probably want OR instead of AND.

Comment: Use table aliases for part_attribute, e.g. pa1 and pa2.

Comment: OR retrieves products with either attribute, I want products that have both attributes.

Comment: I see. Give us some sample table data, and wanted result.

Comment: `DISTINCT *` is going to be disappointing. Also, it's not that this query won't return anything. Rather, it would result in an error of the 'not unique table/alias' variety!!!!!!!!!!!!

Comment: I've made an attempt at showing the data. There could be other searchproducts, with parts that have the same attributes combination.

Comment: Use aliases as per jarlh in the second coment,

Comment: If you like, consider following this simple two-step course of action: 1. If you have not already done so, provide proper DDLs (and/or an sqlfiddle) so that we can more easily replicate the problem. 2. If you have not already done so, provide a desired result set that corresponds with the information provided in step 1.

Comment: Thanks I will do that.

Comment: You are checking the same field has 2 different values from the part_attribute table. If a part can have 2 values you need to check then easiest is to join against that table twice, once for each value.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am struggling to understand your layout of the data (are part_attribute and part_attributeheader different tables), but think you need 2 joins. Something like this:-

```
SELECT DISTINCT * 
FROM searchproduct
JOIN part ON searchproduct.id = part.searchproduct_id
INNER JOIN part_attribute p0 ON part.id = p0.part_id
INNER JOIN part_attribute P1 ON p.id = P1.part_attributeheader_id
WHERE (p0.name = 'Colour' AND p0.value IN ('Black')) 
AND (P1.name = 'Size' AND P1.value IN ('11'));
```